# I am getting an text error ' required positional argument: 'coro' ' while making error handler for one of command in my discord bot

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Text(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  
  @commands.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
  async def text(self, ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(message)
    
  @text.error()
  async def text_error(self, error, ctx):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
      await ctx.send(f"{ctx.auhtor.mention} You don't Have permission to use this command")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Text(client))
```

The whole error:

```
File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 609, in _load_from_module_spec
    raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.text' raised an error: TypeError: error() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please format your code so that it is easier to read for others.

Comment: Please post the **complete** error traceback!

Answer (score 1):

That is happening because you have some mistakes in your code:

1. `@text.error()` should be replaced with `@text.error`
2. You swaped `ctx` and `error` in `text_error` function
3. You made a typo in `{ctx.auhtor.mention}`

Final code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


class Text(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def text(self, ctx, *, message):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        await ctx.send(message)

    @text.error
    async def text_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
            await ctx.send(
                f"{ctx.author.mention} You don't Have permission to use this command"
            )


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Text(client))
```